# ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table in MULTI DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql

I use a temporary table `t` with these queries in order to delete duplicated rows from `comment` table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
        id INT NOT NULL,
        hash BINARY(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    INDEX(hash) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t (id, hash)
    SELECT id, UNHEX(SHA1(body))
        FROM `comment`;

DELETE FROM `comment`
       USING t AS t1,
             t AS t2
       WHERE t1.id = comment.id
         AND t2.hash = t1.hash AND t2.id < t1.id;
```

But at delete stage, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'comment' in MULTI DELETE
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to execute a off PostgreSQL syntax `USING`in the `DELETE` statement  on a MySQL server.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `USING` in `DELETE`.  I think you want:

```
DELETE c
    FROM `comment` c JOIN
         t t1
         ON t1.id = c.id JOIN
         t t2
         ON t2.hash = t1.hash AND t2.id < t1.id;
```

I suspect there are simpler ways to express this logic.  Perhaps you should ask another question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you are implementing.

Comment: Maybe there are let convoluted way to do so. But this works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Please correct the 4th line, which should be: `ON t1.id = c.id JOIN`

Comment: MySQL 5.7 upwards clearly [does support `USING` in `DELETE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html#idm46092677022416).